# Getting url on first render

Tags: next.js

I'n new to next.js

I'm trying to get the url on first render. I have a json file with allot of url's from an old website that redirects to what the url in on the new website.

So if first render url is a.mywebsite.com/hello i need to check if that url is in my redirect.json file. If a match it should redirect to fx mywebsite.com/a/hello.

I have no luck getting the first render url in my _documents.tsx or slug.tsx file. It it not possible inside the SSR with getServerSideProps?

Answer (score 0):

You should easily be able to get that using the `context` object that exposed to you.

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#context-parameter

Seems you can either get it from `context.resolvedUrl` or find it inside `context.req`

Comment: context.resolvedUrl only gives me path. I can also get host. But I need the complete url to know if its with https etc.